# migrating to mysql in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, sqlite

I want to migrate from sqlite3 to MySQL in Django. First I used below command:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json
```

then I changed the settings of my Django application and configured it with my new MySQL database. Finally, I used the following command:

```
python manage.py loaddata datadump.json
```

but I got this error :

> integrityError: Problem installing fixtures: The row in table
>   'django_admin_log' with primary key '20' has an invalid foregin key:
>   django_admin_log.user_id contains a value '19' that does not have a
>   corresponding value in auth_user.id.

Comment: check your foreign_key constraint properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have consistency error in your data, django_admin_log table refers to auth_user which does not exist. sqlite does not enforce foreign key constraints, but mysql does. You need to fix data and then you can import it into mysql.

Comment: how should I solve this problem is there any tools which can help me ?

Comment: From error message, you could try to delete from django_admin_log row with id 20 and repeat migration. You can do that in sqlite database, or you can edit the json dump. You can also find all invalid rows with `SELECT id FROM django_admin_log WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM auth_user)`

Comment: That answer is, although old and accepted, partly incorrect. It's only the value '19' that does not exist, it's _not_ the table 'auth_user' - that on for sure exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move my database from a postgres to a MySql-Database.

This worked for me:

Export (old machine):

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural --all --indent=2 --exclude=sessions  --format=xml > dump.xml
```

Import (new machine):
(note that for older versions of Django you'll need **syncdb** instead of migrate)

```
manage.py migrate --no-initial-data
```

Get SQL for resetting Database:

```
manage.py sqlflush
```

setting.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'asdf',
        'USER': 'asdf',
        'PASSWORD': 'asdf',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    #IMPORTANT!!
    'OPTIONS': {
             "init_command": "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;",
        },
}

python manage.py loaddata dump.xml
```