# Migrate SQLite3 database to MySQL in Django

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite, django-cms, dbmigrate

I am developing a website using Django 1.11 and Django-CMS with `python3`. Initially I used the default database `sqlite3`, however, now I want it to migrate to `mysql`. I have found several solutions online like

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41045999/6424055)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38079101/6424055)

However, both did not work. For the first solution I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute '_node_cache'
```

and for the second solution there was this error:

```
Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=1): (1062, "Duplicate entry 'cms-placeholder' for key 'django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq'"
```

In both examples, I used a empty database and migrated first.

Any help please?

Comment: does your mysql database connect correctly?

Comment: @TheDumbfounds yes it does

Answer (score 1):

Django's content types get tricky. Try deleting the content of `django_content_type` from the database after running migrations, but before loading the fixtures:

```
python manage.py dbshell
DELETE FROM django_content_type;
```

If it loads successfully, run migrations again to fill in any missing entries in `django_content_type`. Good luck!